# How do I disable Excel 2016 auto horizontal scrolling?

Tags: excel

When I expand a column that contains a lot of text and is very wide (more than the screen's width), Excel automatically horizontally scrolls so that the edge of the column is at the edge of the window.

That way it is impossible for me to reduce the width of that column because I cannot click and drag its edge! Is there a way to fix that annoyance? They thought this would be a feature, but I consider it an annoyance if it is not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Excel 2016, but here is how to reduce the column width to fit on the screen in older versions:

1. Right click on the column header (above the top row of editable cells).
2. Click *Column Width*
3. In the box that pops up, enter a number (try 150 to start with)

Obviously, you can repeat this with different numbers to get the column size that suits you.

Comment: That works thanks! But yet it is a bit inconvenient. Isn't there a way to disable this annoying "feature" ?

Comment: What you really want is a "maximum column width" setting, but there is nothing like that in Excel.  I have added another answer you could use to automatically readjust the column width after you resize it (any then select another cell in the same column).

Comment: This really is a bug. I wonder the people who designed this feature/bug ever used the product themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually still manage to get the edge right edge of the column if you keep clicking the right arrow of the horizontal scroll bar, it should automatically expand the selection. Sometimes this can be a bit of bother though, [here is some info from Microsoft about scroll lock](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Turn-off-Scroll-Lock-a78492cc-c124-4782-a38b-df46669520e0) in Excel. To turn it off in Excel, see the Troubleshooting Scroll Lock, right click on the bottom bar (Excel status bar) and untick scroll lock. This will stop auto scrolling, and of course you can always turn it back on after!

Comment: That doesn't work, I am not sure we are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA, you could use this code in the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (ActiveSheet.Columns(Target.Column).ColumnWidth > 150) Then
        ActiveSheet.Columns(Target.Column).ColumnWidth = 150
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    End If
End Sub
```